# Document-based custom NSWindowController not saving window state

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I have a document-based macOS app that uses a custom `NSWindowController`. This window controller instantiates itself with a nib largely for a toolbar but programmatically sets its content.

```swift
final class ProjectWindowController: NSWindowController {

    lazy var splitViewController = HostingSplitViewController()

    override var document: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            guard let project = document as? ProjectDocument else { return }
            splitViewController.document = project
        }
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(windowNibName: "ProjectWindowController")
    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        contentViewController = splitViewController
    }
}
```

Then in my document, I instantiate and add this window controller in `makeWindowControllers()`

```swift
    override func makeWindowControllers() {
        let windowController = ProjectWindowController()
        addWindowController(windowController)
    }
```

The problem I'm seeing is that *no window state* is saved this way. The `frameAutosaveName` is properly set but every new window is a bizarre tiny version and nothing is remembered. If I flip  the process around and instead of use `makeWindowControllers()` use `windowNibName`, then my custom controller never gets created. This is despite marking the nib's `File Owner` as my custom class, `ProjectWindowController`.

```swift
override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name? { "ProjectWindowController" }
```

This *will save window state* but none of my content appears because it claims its owner is a generic `NSWindowController`. Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you want to restore the state or the frame?

Comment: For now the frame would suffice. Shouldn't this be automatic? But if you also have resources for full state handy I would love both.